# How to find and execute all "uninstall" normal files?

Tags: find

I have a couple of `uninstall` files. I want to find all of them and execute them one by one. I know about find and exec combination so I tried

```
find . -name uninstall -exec {}\;
```

But this gives me such error :

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Since it is a regular file, I can't give it argument. I just run it like this in terminal

```
./uninstall
```

How can I find and execute these files?

Comment: Maybe it's not liking the lack of any dressing on the found-item marker.  Try `-exec ./{} \;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a shell to start the file with, e.g.

```
find . -name uninstall -exec sh {} \;
```

or

```
find . -name uninstall -exec bash {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

The `;` must be a separate argument, that's the argument that tells `find` where the command to run ends:

```
find . -name uninstall -type f -exec {} \;
```

With some `find` implementations, you can add a `-executable` predicate before the `-exec` to only bother trying to execute files that are actually executable.

Answer (score 0):

Via **find** + **shell** pipeline:

```
find . -name uninstall | sh
```

Comment: It works but it does not wait for user prompt.I mean uninstall files ask me if i am sure to delete.Your function immediately skips to the next file without my input